# Getting jasper Exception

Tags: java, jsp

From Java Class set the value in the bellow map ans set it within request.

```
Map<String,String> responseMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
responseMap.put("requestId", "test");
request.setAttribute("nomineeResponseMap", responseMap);
```

Now I am trying to get this request from the jsp page but unable to get data from this Map.

Below code which I used in JSP page.

From JSP Page:

```
Object responseMap = request.getAttribute("nomineeResponseMap");
  if(responseMap instanceof LinkedHashMap) {
    Map<String, String> newMap = (LinkedHashMap) responseMap;
    System.out.println("yesss");
}
```

Below Exception I am getting while running the program:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP

An error occurred at line: 36 in the jsp file: /form/EDCPRequestSuccess.jsp
Generated servlet error:
The type Map is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <String, String>

An error occurred at line: 36 in the jsp file: /form/EDCPRequestSuccess.jsp
Generated servlet error:
Syntax error, parameterized types are only available if source level is 5.0
```

Why I am getting the above exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your server is running using JDK 1.5 or higher version. The issue is caused by wrong JSP compiler setting.
For Tomcat server, the setting could be found in `$TOMCAT_HOME/conf/web.xml`. The error is throwed if `compilerSourceVM` and `compilerTargetVM` are set to 1.4 or lower version.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>compilerSourceVM</param-name>
        <param-value>1.4</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>compilerTargetVM</param-name>
        <param-value>1.4</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>3</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Comment: I am using jboss 4.0 server. So where I will set this property in JBoss?

Comment: I am not familiar with JBoss, after download JBoss 4.0.5 and do some testing. Modifying `$JBOSS_HOME/server/default/deploy/jbossweb-tomcat55.sar/conf/web.xml` work for me. There is another file `$JBOSS_HOME/server/all/deploy/jbossweb-tomcat55.sar/conf/web.xml` with the same content. If the first one does not work, you can also modify this one.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your JFK version, I think you are using less than jdk1.5